# df(X) of Frobenius norm of a matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms

I have a function
$$f(X)=||AX-B||_F$$

I need to find $df(X)$. As I understand the function equals to
$$\sqrt{Tr[(AX-B)^T(AX-B)]}$$

What are the steps to obtain $df(X)$?

$$||AX-B||_F^{-1}Tr((AX-B)AdX)$$

Comment: Have you attempted this equation? It would be preferable to see any attempts that you have made on this so people on the Mathematics Stack Exchange can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this using the chain rule, that is, write $f = \| \cdot \|_F \circ g$, where $g(X) := A X - B$ is a smooth function. Now, $d g(X)$ is simple and [$d \| \cdot \|_F(Y) = \frac{1}{\| Y \|_F} Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3232958/second-derivative-of-frobenius-norm?rq=1) for $Y \in \mathbb R^{n \times n} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.
Hence $$d f(X) = \frac{1}{\| A X - B \|_F} A^{T} (A X - B).$$

Another option is to differentiate $f^2 = \| A X - B \|_F^2$, which is easier; $d(f^2)(X) = 2 A^{T}(A X - B)$ and the use the chain rule to differentiate $f = \sqrt{\ } \circ f^2$.